Having $k$ failures in $n$ trials with binomial distribution $B(p,n)$
I'm working on a question that I found and I'm not sure whether I'm not able to solve it because I'm missing a point or if I misunderstood the question.
Basically, assuming a binomial distribution with $n$ trials and a probability of $p$ for a success (therefore $1-p$ for failure), then by definition $p_k:=\mathbb{P}(${k successes}$)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.
Now, for $q_k=1-p_k$ I want to prove that $q_k$ is the probability of $k$ successes in n trials for a binomial distribution $B(1-p,n)$.
I don't seem to find a proper angle here. My approach was to go for $1-p_k = ((1-p)+p)^n-p_k$ and use the binomial theorem but the terms that follow when I go on calculating just don't seem to add up.
If necessary, I can add my calculations, however, I first wanted to check if I had an obvious issue of understanding the problem (considering that this result implies basically the probability of not having exactly $k$ successes is like the probability of having $k$ failures?) or if there's a widely known approach to this that I haven't figured out yet.
Any help/hint is much appreciated.
Thanks!

success and failure are just labels so your logic seems to be fine.

It is not correct as written:
Suppose $n=2$ and $p=\frac13$ and you start with $Bin(2,\frac23)$.
Then $p_0=\frac19$ and $p_1=p_2=\frac49$.
If $q_k=1-p_k$ then this means $q_0=1-\frac19=\frac89$ and $q_1=q_2=1-\frac49=\frac59$.
That is not the probability mass function of anything, since the three probabilities add up to more than $1$.

What I suspect you intended to ask was when $q=1-p$ whether $q_k=p_{n-k}$,
i.e. whether you get $Bin(n,q)$ being the same distribution as $Bin(n,1-p)$.
Numerically this is asking whether ${n \choose k} q^k(1-q)^{n-k}={n \choose n-k}p^{n-k}(1-p)^{n-(n-k)}$,
and the answer is yes, because ${n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}$ and $q^k=(1-p)^k=(1-p)^{n-(n-k)}$ and $(1-q)^{n-k}=p^{n-k}$: all you have done is swap success and failure.
In my earlier example, $p_0=\frac19$ and $p_1=p_2=\frac49$ would give  $q_0=q_1=\frac49$ and $q_2=\frac19$, which is indeed the probability mass function of $Bin(2, \frac13)$.

Thanks a lot for the quick answer and the example in particular. Now since this seems so strange to me, I just wanted to check for the original question in "Probability Essentials" of Jacod and Protter: "Let $p_k = \mathbb{P}($k successes$)$ and $q_k = 1 − p_k$. Show that the $q_k$ are the probabilities of singletons for a Binomial distribution $B(1 − p, n)$." Did I misread this or is the problem just wrongly posed?

The book question (Exercise 4.2) looks wrong, but you would be able to find a Poisson approximation if it had been written correctly.

Thanks again for the answers. For completeness, here‘s a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622348/help-interpret-exercise-4-2-in-probability-essentials-jacod-protter

@Leoncino Well spotted - that has the same conclusion about the same exercise, so this a duplicate.
